# How to get authenticated user in event listener - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to identify proper way to to get authenticated user's information in the event listener.

I can alway use `\Auth:user()` which seems to work but I don't think it will work if I queue the listener.

Do I need to add the authenticated user to the event class as property for each event, or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Pass it through the event. When the event is fired you have access to the `Auth::user()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the user [through the event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#defining-events). You should have access to the `Auth` facade when the event is triggered.

Event:

```
class SomeEvent
{
    // Public so that it will be accessible from the listener
    public $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }
}
```

Listener:

```
class SomeListener
{
    public function handle(SomeEvent $event)
    {
        // Get the public property `$user` from the event
        $authUser = $event->user;
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
event(new SomeEvent(auth()->user()));
```

Comment: thats what I thought.  I fire events from repositories and sometimes from model. Do you it's think right idea to use auth()->user() from there? Instead of passing it on to event. Can I put auth()->user() directly in the constructor of the event?

Comment: Yeah you can. I image it would be a bit harder to write tests for the listeners, as you wouldn't be able to just pass a user to the model constructor. But it will work